# How to replace (or extend) vanila Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wonder is there a way to extend vanila  directive by HTML that will be wrapped around input.

Basically I want Angular to compile

```
<input type='checkbox'>
```

into

```
<div class='checkbox'>
  <input type='ckeckbox'>
```

(for checkbox replacement purposes).

Comment: You might want to take a look at this discussion - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/dOMu1wjXt_Q

Comment: While this question is still open, I made workaround by simply adding tElement.wrap '<div class="checkbox"></div>' to compile function. Key to this was understanding that compile function should return the linking function after performing DOM changes.